# Calculating polygon width using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, python-script-tool, arcgis-10.4

I am trying to calculate an average width of a large set of polygons.

I found the script below researching the topic.
The function is:

```
def add_average_width(featureClass, averageWidthField='Width'):
    '''
    (str, [str]) -> str

    Calculate the average width of each feature in the feature class. The width
        is reported in units of the feature class' projected coordinate systems'
        linear unit.

    Returns the name of the field that is populated with the feature widths.
    '''
    import arcpy
    from math import pi

    # Add the width field, if necessary
    fns = [i.name.lower() for i in arcpy.ListFields(featureClass)]
    if averageWidthField.lower() not in fns:
        arcpy.AddField_management(featureClass, averageWidthField, 'DOUBLE')

    fnsCur = ['SHAPE@LENGTH', 'SHAPE@AREA', averageWidthField]
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(featureClass, fnsCur) as cur:
        for row in cur:
            perim, area, width = row
            row[-1] = ((perim/pi) * area) / (perim**2 / (4 * pi))
            cur.updateRow(row)

    return averageWidthField
```

I replace 'featureclass' with the feature I am trying to calculate widths on, and am lost on how to actually execute the script.

I added the script to a toolbox, but am unsure if I am setting the parameters up correctly.

Forgive my Python ignorance - new to programming.

Comment: Could you elaborate what do you mean by average width? Average width along the length axis of each polygon? Or average max width of each polygon?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should review the Help on [Creating a new Python script](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/creating-a-new-python-script-module.htm) and start reading up on [ArcPy.GetParameterAsText()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/getparameterastext.htm).

At the moment you have not defined any parameters for a Python script tool.

What you have is a Python function which you need to modify to become suitable as a Python script tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to execute your function, you could call the function at the end of your script.

```
def add_average_width(featureClass, averageWidthField='Width'):
    '''
    (str, [str]) -> str

    Calculate the average width of each feature in the feature class. The width
        is reported in units of the feature class' projected coordinate systems'
        linear unit.

    Returns the name of the field that is populated with the feature widths.
    '''
    import arcpy
    from math import pi

    # Add the width field, if necessary
    fns = [i.name.lower() for i in arcpy.ListFields(featureClass)]
    if averageWidthField.lower() not in fns:
        arcpy.AddField_management(featureClass, averageWidthField, 'DOUBLE')

    fnsCur = ['SHAPE@LENGTH', 'SHAPE@AREA', averageWidthField]
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(featureClass, fnsCur) as cur:
        for row in cur:
            perim, area, width = row
            row[-1] = ((perim/pi) * area) / (perim**2 / (4 * pi))
            cur.updateRow(row)

    return averageWidthField

featureClass = "path/to/your/featureClass"
add_average_width(featureClass)
```

You could use the Python IDLE to run the script.